# How to escape special element when converting xml file to Java object using XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

How to escape special element when converting xml file to Java object using XStream?
For example,the xml file like below

```xml
<People id="173278">
<Name>A</Name>
<Age>18</Age>
</People>
```

But, sometimes the xml file will add `<School>` element. I only need name and age fields.
How to escape the `<School>` element?

Java Object

```java
public class People {
  private String Name;
  private int Age;

  public void setName(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
  }

  public void setAge(int Age) {
    this.Age = Age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return  Name;
  }
  public int getAge() {
    return Age;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed to provide the class School and how it is linked to People class.
We need more information in order to help you.

I don't think there is any method in XStream which can escape elements the way you want.

We need to manipulate the classes only.